# Python code error after splitting into multiple functions

Tags: python, function

I'm new to python, and I started out by doing some excercises. I came with a working code, but after dividing the code into multiple functions I got an error.

> TypeError: averages() missing 1 required positional argument: 'average_grades'

This is my code:

```
def averages(line, average_grades):
    if line == '':
        return
    name_grades = line.split('_')
    student_name = name_grades[0]
    grades = [float(n) for n in name_grades[-1].split(' ')]
    average_grades(student_name, grades)
    print('{} has an average grade of {:.2}'.format(student_name, average_grade))


def average_grades(grades):
    average_grade = sum(grades) / len(grades)
    averages(average_grade)
    return


file = open('geo_grades_1_input.txt').read().split('\n')
print("Report for group 2b")

for line in file:
    averages(line)

print("End of report")
```

Thanks for your time in regards!

Comment: The `averages` function requires *two* arguments to be passed.  Both cases of the function being called, only pass one argument.  (And different in each case)

Comment: What part of the error message is not clear?

Comment: There's a lot of inconsistency in the posted code.  Your `averages` function is declared to take two arguments, `line` and `average_grades`.  But it's called with only one argument.  Further, since `average_grades` is a function, you probably don't want it to also be a parameter of `averages`.  Then, inside `averages`, you call `average_grades` with two arguments, even though it is defined to take one argument.  You need to fix all of this.  The number of arguments you pass to a function must match the number of arguments in its definition.

Comment: Additionally (to my previous comment), there are many other errors which will prevent this from running properly. Just resolve each error in turn.

Answer (score 0):

When you split code into multiple functions, make sure you have a clear understanding of what each function does -- what it takes as an input, what it produces as output.  It helps if you give it a name that reflects that purpose.

In this case you probably want to have one function that returns the average of a particular set of grades:

```
def average(grades):
    return sum(grades) / len(grades)
```

and another function that prints the average grades for a particular line:

```
def print_average_grades(line):
    if line == '':
        return
    name_grades = line.split('_')
    student_name = name_grades[0]
    grades = [float(n) for n in name_grades[-1].split(' ')]
    print(f'{student_name} has an average grade of {average(grades)}')
```

In the `print_average_grades` function, we call `average(grades)` to get the `average` of the `grades` list.  Note that we don't pass the `average` function `student_name` as an argument, because it wouldn't know what to do with it.  `average` only cares about the list of grades, not the name of the student they came from.

We don't call `print_average_grades` from inside `average`, because `average`'s only job is to compute the average and return it, not to print it (and it doesn't have access to the `line` that `print_average_grades` depends on anyway) -- `print_average_grades` needs to call `average` to do its job, but not vice versa.

You could split `print_average_grades` down a little further, perhaps, by having a function whose job is to parse `line` into `name` and `grades`:

```
def parse_name_grades(line):
    name_grades = line.split('_')
    return name_grades[0], [float(n) for n in name_grades[-1].split(' ')]

def print_average_grades(line):
    if not line:
        return
    name, grades = parse_name_grades(line)
    print(f'{name} has an average grade of {average(grades)}')
```